# Routing in laravel - error 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I have problem with routing page and realizations. 
When the page routing is before realizations, page it works, realization do not work. Similarly...
When the realization routing is before page routing, realization works, page do not work. Display error 404.

My routing page:

```
Route::get('{page}/{subs?}', ['uses' => 'PagesController@getPage'])
    ->where(['page' => '^((?!admin).)*$', 'subs' => '.*']);
```

My routing realizarion:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('realizacje/{slug}', 'PagesController@getRealization')
        ->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
});
```

My controller PagesController:

```
public function getPage($slug){
    $realizations = Realization::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    $page = Page::findBySlug($slug);
    if (!$page)
    {
        abort(404, 'Please go back to our <a href="'.url('').'">homepage</a>.');
    }

    $this->data['title'] = $page->title;

    $metatag = $page->extras;
    $metatag = json_decode($metatag, true);


    $this->data['page'] = $page->withFakes();
    return view('pages.templates.'.$page->template, $this->data)
    ->with('metatag',$metatag)
    ->with('realizations',$realizations);
}

public function getRealization($slug){

    $realization = Realization::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    $realizations = Realization::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('pages.templates.'.$realization->template)

    ->with('realizations',$realizations);

}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Routings do not work. Routing pages for displaying subpages. Routing realization for displaying subpages realizations. When I run both, 'subpages page' or 'subpages realizations' only one routing works. Depends who is first

Comment: Ah: put the second route first will fix this

Comment: When I put the second route first, routing pages not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: i don't know Laravel. I develop in Symfony.

But maybe it could help.

The problem could be in Your routes URIs definitions:

```
Route::get('{page}/{subs?}'...

Route::get('realizacje/{slug}'...
```

Maybe try to modify Your page URI like this so router won't match those two actions:

```
Route::get('pages/{page}/{subs?}'...
Route::get('realizacje/{slug}'...
```

Or try to modify where() conditions.

Comment: Probably the best way. The fact is that "realizacje" will be interpreted as the {page} parameter, so routes will conflict.

Comment: @iArcadia Exactly. :)